# Can't get information from mongodb

Tags: node.js, angular

I am working on a quiz application with Angular 8 and node.js .I've inserted the questions, options and answers in the db, can see them in the database but when I try to get them through http://localhost:/8888/api/quiz nothing happens. There's just an empty array. No errors are shown in the console. Everything else is working besides this feature. I can register, login and logout a user but can't get the quiz questions and options.

Here are my routers in the config file:

```
const router = require('../routes/')

module.exports = (app) => {

    app.use('/api/user', router.user);
    app.use('/api/quiz', router.quiz);
    app.get('*', (req, res) => { res.send('Something went wrong');});
}
```

Quiz model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const quizSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    id: {
        type: String
    },
    question: {
        type: String
    },
    firstOption: {
        type: String
    },
    secondOption: {
        type: String
    },
    thirdOption: {
        type: String
    },
    fourthOption: {
        type: String
    },
    answer: {
        type: String
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Quiz', quizSchema);
```

Quiz controller

```
const models = require('../models');

module.exports = {

    get: {
        many: (req, res, next) => {
            models.quiz.find()   
            .then((quiz) => (res.send(quiz)))
            .catch(next);       
        }
    }
}
```

and routes in the quiz

```
const controllers = require('../controllers/');

const router = require('express').Router();

router.get('', controllers.quiz.get.many);

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Can you changing the end point to `/` like this `router.get('/', controllers.quiz.get.many);`

Comment: Tried but the result is still the same -  an empty array.

Comment: In that case, collection must be empty

Comment: I can see the information in the db when I type in mongodb db.quiz.find()